# Generalizing $f(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{x^n}+1}=\left(1-2^{(n-1)/n}\right )\zeta(n^{-1})\Gamma(1+n^{-1})$

Tags: integration, zeta-functions

I have come up with the following solution to this integral, but is just incomplete to my standards
$$f(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{x^n}+1}=\left(1-2^{(n-1)/n}\right )\zeta(n^{-1})\Gamma(1+n^{-1})$$

Seems to only work for $x\in\Bbb{N},x\gt 2$

This identity, therefore does not apply to $n=1$, and we all know that $f(1)=\ln 2$ because $\zeta(1)$ diverges.

So my question is this: How can you generalize the integral solution I gave to fit the case $n=1$?

Comment: Just set $\zeta(1) = \gamma$ :D

Comment: You may want to check [the integral representation of the Dirichlet eta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Integral_representations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the formula does 
 apply if you perform the limiting procedure correctly. Notice that

$$
2^{(n-1)/n}-1\sim_{n\rightarrow 1}(n-1)\log(2)+\mathcal{O}(n-1)^2
$$

[and](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)

$$
-\zeta(n^{-1})\sim_{n\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{n-1}+\mathcal{O}(1)
$$

Therefore we obtain

> $$
> -\zeta(n^{-1})(2^{(n-1)/n}-1)\sim_{n\rightarrow 1}\log(2)+\mathcal{O}(n-1)
> $$

which yields together with $\Gamma(2)=1$  the desired result!

Comment: A typo on my part. Nice solution! I did indeed leave out that limit, which is important truly

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^{x^n}+1}
&=\frac1n\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac1n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}{e^x+1}\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^\infty x^{\frac1n-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}e^{-kx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{1/n}}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac1n-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\frac1n\eta\left(\frac1n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):
$$
\begin{align}
\eta(s)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\\[6pt]
&=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and as you say, $\eta(1)=\log(2)$.

See [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1711314).