# Limit involving Zeta function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

> Evaluate
>
> $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} (x-1) \zeta (x)$$

I'm not much familiar with the properties of zeta function. An elementary solution is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See the Wikipedia page for the Riemann Zeta function:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/how-to-show-that-the-laurent-series-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-has-gamma-as/176834#176834

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The detail of answer depends on how you define $\zeta(s)$, but if you are working with the definition

$$ \zeta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}, \quad s > 1 $$

then notice that the following inequality

$$ \frac{1}{s-1} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^s} \leq \zeta(s) \leq 1 + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^s} = \frac{s}{s-1} $$

immediately yields

$$ \lim_{s \downarrow 1} (s-1)\zeta(s) = 1. $$

Answer (score 4):

Let me expand on the hint given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412668).

---

The zeta function is the sum of the series
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}
$$
The sum of the even terms is
$$
2^{-s}\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^s}
$$
For any series, subtracting twice the sum of the even terms from the total sum gives the alternating sum:
$$
\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{n^s}
$$
Therefore, applying L'Hôpital,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to1^+}(s-1)\zeta(s)
&=\lim_{s\to1^+}\frac{s-1}{\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)}\lim_{s\to1^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac1{n^s}\\
&=\frac1{\log(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac1n\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: >For any series, subtracting twice the sum of the even terms from the total sum gives the alternating sum

Why do this happen? Can you give me a proof?

Comment: Oh, I got it now. $a_n - 2a_n = -a_n$. But I think you meant $(-1)^{n+1}$ then, since the series will start in odd.

Comment: @dude3221: yes, thank you. It's fixed.